# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default

Tags: kotlin, jpa, gradle

I get the following error:

```
[16:16:45 WARN]: [jakarta.persistence.spi] jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86) ~[?:?]
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55) ~[?:?]
```

When using:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.6.Final')
implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1')
}
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>me.janic.database.PlayerEntity</class>
        <class>me.janic.database.ReviveTokenEntity</class>
        <class>me.janic.database.StatsEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/1l1c"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the persistence.xml file is located in META-INF/persistence.xml. I tried different versions of hibernate but I can not get it to work. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: The file needs to be named `persistence.xml` not `persistance.xml`.

Comment: It is named persistence.xml

Comment: I checked the output jar and can confirm the the persistence.xml is in the META-INF dir. But it seems not to be loaded?

Comment: see https://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/ - `org.hibernate:hibernate-core-jakarta:6.1.6.Final ; 
org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:3.0.0
`

Comment: @PrasadU None of these work for me.

Comment: Could you include the full stacktrace instead of the snippet you have now? Could you also include your full list of dependencies (make sure that there aren't conflicting ones in there).